# LDAP error: "no database configured for that naming context" when adding custom objectclass

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have configured an openLDAP server for testing purposes and am trying to add a few users from the actual LDAP server. The problem is that they have some attributes that are not defined in the default object classes- top, person or organizationalPerson. So I am trying to define my own object class- `user` with one new attribute for start called `instanceType`. This is the schema file I created- `object_class.schema`:

```
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.4.1.6
        NAME 'instanceType'
        DESC 'instanceType attribute'
        EQUALITY caseExactMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
        SINGLE-VALUE )

objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.4.2.1
        NAME 'user'
        DESC 'user object'
        SUP top
        STRUCTURAL
        MUST ( cn $ instanceType ) )
```

I also created `object_class.conf`:

```
include /ldap-data/object_class.schema
```

After that I am running `slaptest -f /ldap-data/object_class.conf -F /ldap-data/schemas/` which produces the following file- `/ldap-data/schemas/cn=config/cn=schema/cn={0}object_class.ldif`
I am stopping the slapd service but when I run `slapadd -l /ldap-data/schemas/cn\=config/cn\=schema/cn\=\{0\}object_class.ldif -n 0`
I receive:

```
slapadd: line 1: database #0 (cn=config) not configured to hold "cn={0}object_class"; no database configured for that naming context
_#################### 100.00% eta   none elapsed            none fast!         
Closing DB...
```

Is my schema wrong? I tried finding the attributes for the "user" data class which I thought are standard but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same Problem today.

Check your "cn={0}object_class.ldif". The "dn:" should say "cn={0}object_class". Edit this to
"dn: cn=object_class,cn=schema,cn=config"
and your "cn" to
"cn: object_class"

Worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).